# Парсер координат по заданым названиям

Tags: карты, алгоритм, google-maps-api, javascript

Есть множество(около 2400 записей) названий горнолыжных курортов. Вобщем каждый из них находится точно в [google maps](http://maps.google.ru/maps?tab=wl&q=Marbach).

Нужно сделать скрипт, который пройдется по всем и вернет мне координаты по каждой записи.
В простейшем случае понятно как делать, а как лучше определять ошибку? Я думаю, что ошибкой можно считать, если возвращается несколько результатов, тогда прогонять дополнительные уточняющие запросы? Или сохранять все и потом вручную по каждой проверять,но руками это очень не хорошо - 2400 записей будет проверять. :)

Подскажите алгоритм оптимальный, или может в api есть какие-нибудь полезные штуки для такой задачи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно, в [Google Map v.3](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html) есть класс [google.maps.Geocoder](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Geocoder). В нем реализован поиск координат по адресам и названиям объектов. Результат - массив с названиями и координатами. Если результат не однозначный, то массив будет состоять из нескольких наборов координат. [Здесь](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/index.html) есть примеры.

Comment: спасибо, посмотрю =)