# Google maps. Парсинг по названиям.

Tags: карты, google-maps-api, javascript

Я уже задавал [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/20936/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC) , но его не заметили, поэтому еще раз прошу подсказки.
Есть в базе 2400 записи названий горнолыжных курортов. Надо каким-то образом спарсить по всем координаты. Как это сделать, может есть сервисы готовые, либо же надо search api для карт использовать? Но в таком случае, как корректировать ошибку, так как выдается больше чем один результат , на каждый тайтл.

Comment: Из готовых сервисов, можете посмотреть [тут](https://outscraper.com/google-maps-parser/).

Answer (score 3):

Вот хорошая [статья](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/webdev/110460/) про API google maps. В двух словах: Гугл предоставляет библиотеку - Geocoder - обратившись к которой можно определить координаты по названию и название по координатам, например [вот так](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Иваново&sensor=false&language=ru). Ответ в json - или xml - формате.

По поводу корректности результатов - тут, наверное, все равно придется пройтись вручную. Хотя, если Вы считаете наличие более 1го результата ошибкой - эту ситуацию легко отловить и записать имя объекта, чтобы потом просмотреть вручную.